# Pnotify fails to show the buttons when using with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am using pnotify with jquery and bootstrap3 and the buttons fail to show

I have included both `pnotify.custom.min.css` and `pnotify.custom.min.js` files in the application head

This is the function displaying them

```
<button 'onclick' => 'delete_category(' . $model->id .')'>Delete user</button>


 function delete_category(id) {
    PNotify.prototype.options.styling = "bootstrap3";
     (new PNotify({
        title: 'Confirmation',
        text: 'This will delete the category?',
        icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign',
        hide: false,
        confirm: {
            confirm: true
        },
        buttons: {
            closer: true,
            sticker: false
        },
        history: {
            history: false
        }
    })).get().on('pnotify.confirm', function() {
        alert('Ok, cool.');
    }).on('pnotify.cancel', function() {
        alert('Oh ok. Chicken, I see.');
    });
  }
```

The above shows the pnotify but doesnt display the buttons

[image]

Comment: Using your pnotify custom css and js can you create a jsfiddle / plunker and share it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with the `Pnotify buttons` but with the **`paths`** in which you configure your buttons otherwise they wont show.

> Proof mentioned in the **[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pritishvaidya/g3co6n9d/)**

I assume you are using the `require.js`  *setting the path of the buttons* in the `config` file

The correct way to reference the path is as `pnotify.buttons` and `pnotify.confirm`

```
paths: {
        pnotify: '<path-to-pnotify>/pnotify.core',
        'pnotify.buttons': '<path-to-pnotify>/pnotify.buttons',
        'pnotify.confirm': '<path-to-pnotify>/pnotify.confirm',
    }
```

*The specification of the correct path is important
as mentioned in the issues referenced* [here](https://github.com/sciactive/pnotify/issues/170)

Comment: am using jquery not require

Comment: so it is working as shown in the fiddle,or you can add some more code where you may have changed the buttons or something related to it

Answer (score 2):

Add  bellow jquery  library in your code.

pnotify.buttons.js

pnotify.core.js

pnotify.nonblock.js

Answer (score 0):

Please use in this order

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pnotify/3.2.1/pnotify.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pnotify/3.2.1/pnotify.buttons.css"/>
```

//

```
<script src="https://colorlib.com/polygon/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://colorlib.com/polygon/vendors/pnotify/dist/pnotify.js"></script>
<script src="https://colorlib.com/polygon/vendors/pnotify/dist/pnotify.buttons.js"></script>
```